# The function inside the "if statement" still run even if the "if statement" is no longer satisfied

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i have this script to detect window width and do certain action if satisfy the if statement. 
Yes it works if the "width" is less than 980 but if I resize the window more than 180 it still run the instruction which i dont want.
Ive checked the "width" using  $('#jqWidth').html(width); if the value vary as the window
changes and it varies. Its as if:

1. variable inside the if statement is not being updated as the window width changes (But I doubt this one). or
2. $(window).scroll(function() is still running even if the if statement is not satisfied.

So basically I want to disable slideUp() and slideDown() or $(window).scroll function it self, inside the if statement, once the width is 980 or more than.

THANKS!

```
function jqUpdateSize(){
// Get the width of the viewport
var width = $(window).width();

if(width < 980){
    $(".slideToggle").css({display:'none'});
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() > 535) {
            $(".header").slideUp("slow");
        }
        if($(window).scrollTop() < 535) {
            $(".header").slideDown("slow");
        }      
    });
}
$('#jqWidth').html(width); //for testing purposes if width changes.
}
$(document).ready(jqUpdateSize);    // When the page first loads
$(window).resize(jqUpdateSize);     // When the browser changes size
```

**EDIT**

```
function jqUpdateSize(){
// Get the width of the viewport
var width = $(window).width();

if(width < 980){
    $(".slideToggle").css({display:'none'});
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() > 535) {
            $(".header").slideUp("slow");
        }
        if($(window).scrollTop() < 535) {
            $(".header").slideDown("slow");
        }      
    });
}
$('#jqWidth').html(width); //for testing purposes if width changes.
}else{
    $(window).unbind('scroll');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    jqUpdateSize();
});
$(window).resize(function(){
    jqUpdateSize();
});
```

added "else" on the statement and it worked. Thanks @adeneo for the hint and to @miushock

Comment: This really doesn't make a lot of sense. *What* "variable inside the `if` statement` is not being updated? Why should it be updated? How is the function called?

Comment: The event handlers aren't removed, ever! Once bound, you have to actually unbind to remove.

Comment: @OP Your testing code is flawed. Move the `$('#jqWidth').html(width)` statement inside `jqUpdateSize` to accurately see what's going on. `width` isn't even accessible outside the `jqUpdateSize` function.

Comment: @adeneo I just realised what you're talking about. You're right, the `scroll` handler needs to be removed in the OP's code, instead of piling on more `scroll` handlers on each resize event.

Comment: im so sorry. Ive updated my post. Originally the test code is inside the function. I misplaced it when I transferred the script because I still have working scripts using that function. @adeneo Do you mind sharing how to remove event handler? And Pointy not everyone here is perfect and know everything Im so sorry if it does not make any sense to you.

Comment: Should be as easy as removing everything and doing this -> http://jsfiddle.net/9cZGR/

Comment: Edited the post based from your suggestions and hints and it worked. Just added "else" statement to unbind the scroll function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the handler not being properly link to event, try changing it to

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        jqUpdateSize();
    });
    $(window).resize(function(){
        jqUpdateSize();
    });
```

I'd like to add a bit more to this answer,

defining your handler method in the form of function literal shall work too

```
var jqUpdateSize = function () {...}
```

I'm not sure it's the jquery or browser implementation, but function literals seems being treated as an object better